# Find shortest knight's path between two chessboard squares

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, graph

My function is a solution to the [Knight's Travails](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/ruby-knights-travails) problem.  It receives start and end point coordinates on a chess board, and must return the shortest path from start to end.

```
class Node{
    constructor(coordinates){
        this.value=coordinates
        this.possibleMoves=[]
    }
}

class Tree{
    constructor(startCoordinates){
        this.value=startCoordinates
        this.possibleMoves=[] 

    }
}
 class Knight{
     constructor(){
         this.piece="Knight"
         this.potentialPaths=null 
     }
     moveKnight(start, end, currentPlay,node,q){
            currentPlay=currentPlay||new Tree(start)
            node=node||currentPlay
            let potentialRoutes= this.possibleMoves(start) 
            potentialRoutes.forEach(route=>{
                let newNode= new Node(route)
                node.possibleMoves.push(newNode)
            })  
            q=q||[]
            let nodePossibleMoves=node.possibleMoves 
            nodePossibleMoves.forEach(currentNode=>{
                q.push(currentNode)
            }) 
            while(q[0].value.toString() !== end.toString()){ 
                let newStart=q.shift()
                let newStartPossibleMoves=this.possibleMoves(newStart)
                newStartPossibleMoves.forEach(move=>{
                    q.push(move)
                })
                this.moveKnight(newStart.value, end, currentPlay, newStart, q)   
            }
            return(currentPlay)  
     } 
 
     possibleMoves(coordinates){
         let x=coordinates[0]
         let y=coordinates[1]
         let potentialMoves=[[x-1,y+2], [x-1,y-2],[x-2,y-1],[x-2,y+1],[x+1,y-2], [x+1,y+2], [x+2,y-1], [x+2,y+1]]
         potentialMoves.forEach(move=>{
             let x=move[0]
             let y= move[1] 
             if(x<0  || y<0 || x>7 || y>7){
                 move=null
             }
         })
          return potentialMoves.filter(move=> {
             return move[0]>=0 && move[0]<=7 && move[1] >=0 && move[1] <=7 
        })
     }
 }


 let myKnight= new Knight()
 let pathToEnd=(myKnight.moveKnight([0,0], [5,6]))
 console.log(pathToEnd)
```

Comment: How do you get your answer out of this?  It looks like `pathToEnd` ends up being a `Tree`.  I would expect a list of nodes.